# How to get filtered file name list using scandir in PHP?

Tags: php, file, scandir

I would like to get all files that has '_img' and PDF type in a folder

Instead of using

```
$fileArray = scandir($dir);
foreach ($fileArray as $file) {
    if (preg_match("_img",$file) && pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'pdf'){
        $filteredArray[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Are there any short cut or it is the best way?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells

```
<?php 
  $filteredArray = array();
  foreach (glob($dir."/*_img.pdf") as $filename)
     $filteredArray[] = $filename;
?>
```

There is also [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function which matches filename against a pattern

The last solution is to use [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) with [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php)

Answer (score 2):

To me this works fine.
you walk into you directory and store this to an array.

At this level, an optimisation is not needed. you'll win peanuts losting time to optimize this.